# Continuous Function with Infinite number of Roots

Tags: calculus, functions

Is there a function f that fulfills all of the following:

1) f is continuous on the interval [0,1].

2) f has an infinite number of roots (points for which f(x)=0) in [0,1].

3) f is NOT constantly 0 on any interval inside [0,1]. Meaning: there is no interval [a,b] inside [0,1] such that f(x) is 0 for every x in [a,b].

Thanks a lot!
Ofer

Comment: Thanks for helping! But I think your function does not fulfill (3).

Comment: Why does it not fulfill 3?

Comment: Why? On what interval do you think $f$ is constantly zero?

Comment: Sorry - it's not that it does not fulfill specifically (3) - it's simply not defined on all of [0,1]. It's not defined on 0.

Comment: Oh - I guess you explicitly define f(0)=0. In that case all is good. Thanks you very much!!!

Comment: You _could_ add a defined value at zero, but it would still not be continuous there.

Comment: I think it's continuous in that case. The limit is 0 and the value is 0.

Comment: Whoops, a momentary lapse, I guess I was thinking of path connectedness.

Comment: Okay, if we're all happy with Gerry Myerson's answer then maybe he should make it an answer to be accepted. It's an open and shut case.

Comment: @Geoff, done.${}$

Comment: My only reservation here is that although it's an interesting question, that doesn't seem to be a duplicate after a cursory search, I don't think it follows the SE guidelines, which is why I haven't up voted it as yet. I've been an SE member at several member sites for some time now and I'm trying to either apply the guidelines where I agree or META discuss where I don't and this question includes no indication of attempts at a solution or discussion of what it means. As it stands it's just a bald question.

Comment: @Geoff, you have a point. For what it's worth, it's still up to OP to verify the answer works.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I have in the end up voted the question. I'm in two minds about this principle. One of the general Stack Exchange principles is that a site should end up being a useful body of information. Surely that implies having some bald questions with answers. Ultimately, only looking up answers doesn't really help anyone so we don't need to go out of our way to prevent it. I don't think we need to be so strict about it. I do a lot of written work in my development as a mathematician, I also look up answers when I get stuck and I've had enough. It's easy to be over patronising.

Comment: @GeoffPointer - the reason I've asked is that I was hoping the answer would be "no". If that was the case - my approach for solving an ODE HW assignment had a chance to work. But you proved me wrong (after I've spent many hours on what turned to be a hopeless approach). Thanks again!

Comment: So, if there is a background story to this question, you can edit it and add the detail. The moderators haven't put this on hold without explanation. Try the "improve this question" link below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$f(x)=x\sin (1/x)$ for $x\ne0$, $f(0)=0$.

Comment: @Andres, thanks for the edit.